# apache wicket 9 authentication 2 example issue

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to learn how to do an authenticated login for an apache wicket web application following the authentication-2 example from https://examples9x.wicket.apache.org/index.html.

However my IDE can't find the package containing WicketExamplePage, it can find the org.apache.wicket:wicket-examples package which I'm assuming contains it when it searches maven but it can't use it for some reason.

Does someone know how to correct this issue or how to achieve the same result as the authentication-2 example without using WicketExamplePage?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples are not deployed to Maven Central because they cannot be used as a dependency.

Their source code can be found at https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/master/wicket-examples

WicketExamplePage is used for structuring and styling the examples. You can either copy it locally (but then most probably you will need to also copy its .html and webapp/style.css) or remove it completely.

Comment: Thank you, that put me on the right track to make some progress